# How to apply switchMap by condition?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following rxjs:

```
let state = true;

  iif(
            () => this.mode === MODES.CREATE,
            this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository.create(data).pipe(switchMap(() => this.egrnService.SendRequestGetEGRP())),
            this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository.update(data),
        )
            .pipe(indicate(this.loading$), observableHandlerResponse(this.messageService))
            .subscribe((document) => {
                this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
                this.dialogRef.close(document);
            });
```

My problem is that I want to execute `this.egrnService.SendRequestGetEGRP()` only if first request is done and `state = true`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a condition to your `switchMap` like this:

```
switchMap(() => {
  if (state /* or any other condition */) {
    return this.egrnService.SendRequestGetEGRP();
  } else {
    return EMPTY; // or NEVER; which you should be able to import from 'rxjs' package
  }
})
```